# How to capture output of Flask CLI command in supervisord and redirect it to stdout?

Tags: python, docker, flask, supervisord

This is my Flask CLI script. It awaits for messages from `rabbitmq` and prints them out.

```
import pika
import click
from app import app_queue
from app import RABBITMQ_USER
from app import RABBITMQ_HOST
from app import RABBITMQ_PASSWORD
from app import RABBITMQ_PASSWORD
from app import RABBITMQ_PORT
from app import RABBITMQ_VHOST
from flask import current_app
from flask.cli import with_appcontext
from threading import Event

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(RABBITMQ_USER, RABBITMQ_PASSWORD)
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(RABBITMQ_HOST, RABBITMQ_PORT, RABBITMQ_VHOST, credentials)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()


@app_queue.command("listen", help="Listen to default queue.")
@click.argument("queue", required=False)
@with_appcontext
def consume_message(queue):
    queue = queue if queue else 'results'
    print(f'Command is listening for "{queue}" queue.', flush=True)

    channel.queue_declare(queue, durable=True, exclusive=False)
    channel.basic_consume(queue=queue, on_message_callback=process_results)

    print(f'[*] Waiting for messages. from "{queue}" queue. To exit press CTRL+C', flush=True)
    channel.start_consuming()

    Event().wait()


def process_results(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body, flush=True)
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)
```

The script is executed by `supervisord` which triggers `flask queue listen` command.

```
[program:app_rabbitmq]
user=root
numprocs=1
directory=/src
autostart=true
autorestart=true
process_name=%(program_name)s
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
command=flask queue listen
```

How can I redirect output of Flask CLI command to stdout so I can see it with `docker logs <my_container>` command?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. Here are three things that I did.

- Instead redirecting my log to `/dev/stdout` I redirected it to `/proc/1/fd/1`
- I started **supervisord** in nodaemon mode `supervisord -n`
- I set these two environment variables in my docker image  `export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=True` and `export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`